# Able to run app on Actual device but couldn't call the API

Tags: swift

After I updated Xcode 11, I can run my app on simulator and called API successful but when I run it in actual device, it run successfully however when I perform action with API call, it stop working and keep showing error below:

```
Connection 43: unable to determine interface type without an established connection
Connection 43: unable to determine fallback status without a connection
Task <A0AF23A2-8D27-4310-B03E-02424407114D>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -999 [1:89])
```

I have no idea about this. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

**Apple** has defined stricter rules for TLS server certificates, Starting with iOS 13 beta 4.

[Requirements for trusted certificates in iOS 13 and macOS 10.15](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176)

> All TLS server certificates must comply with these new security
>   requirements in iOS 13 and macOS 10.15:
>
> TLS server certificates and issuing CAs using RSA keys must use key
>   sizes greater than or equal to 2048 bits. Certificates using RSA key
>   sizes smaller than 2048 bits are no longer trusted for TLS.
>
> TLS server certificates and issuing CAs must use a hash algorithm from
>   the SHA-2 family in the signature algorithm. SHA-1 signed certificates
>   are no longer trusted for TLS.
>
> TLS server certificates must present the DNS name of the server in the
>   Subject Alternative Name extension of the certificate. DNS names in
>   the CommonName of a certificate are no longer trusted.
>
> Additionally, all TLS server certificates issued after July 1, 2019
>   (as indicated in the NotBefore field of the certificate) must follow
>   these guidelines:
>
> TLS server certificates must contain an ExtendedKeyUsage (EKU)
>   extension containing the id-kp-serverAuth OID.
>
> TLS server certificates must have a validity period of 825 days or
>   fewer (as expressed in the NotBefore and NotAfter fields of the
>   certificate).

And note:

> Connections to TLS servers violating these new requirements will fail
>   and may cause network failures, apps to fail, and websites to not load
>   in Safari in iOS 13 and macOS 10.15.
>
> Starting with iOS 13 beta 4, the copy attribute of the [httpBodyStream](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest/1409529-httpbodystream)
>   property of [NSMutableURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest) is enforced. If the body data is
>   mutated after the property setter has been called, data sent in the
>   HTTP request won't include that mutation. Invoking the property getter
>   no longer returns a [NSMutableData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutabledata) reference, even when the setter was
>   invoked with data of that type. As of iOS 13 beta 5, apps built using
>   the iOS 12 SDK or previous SDKs use the legacy behavior.

Comment: how should I fix this? any steps or tutorial for it? I can't really understand this...

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/371757 checkout these steps

Comment: is it meaning I have to create self signed certificate to fix this?

Comment: how should I create it?